# Python Map Lambda Memory

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of objects, and I'd like to go through each object and change an attributed. Is there a difference in memory usage between (1) map lambda and (2) going through the list objects one by one.

Here is a simple example code

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = 0

    def set_ID(self):
        self.ID = 1

number = 1000000
list_objects = [F() for i in xrange(n)]
```

There are two ways of using `set_ID`:

One way

```
map(lambda x: x.set_ID(), list_objects)
```

Another way

```
for obj in list_objects:
    obj.set_ID()
```

Comment: yes obj = list_objects[i]

Answer (score 1):

I think the second way is better, `map` is used to apply a function to every item of an `iterable` and return a list of the results, so:

```
map(lambda x: x.set_ID(), list_objects)
```

will actually generate a list of 1000000 `None`, since you did not assign it to a variable, it will be discarded immediately and be garbage collected, since all item in this list is `None`, it will not eat too much memory. The state of your items in `list_objects` are changed because of the `side effect` of your `lambda`, I don't think this is the appropriate way to use `map`.

The second second method has nothing extra object created during the whole process. By the way, it could just be:

```
for obj in list_objects:
    obj.set_ID()
```